# Java eclipse location coding error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

GETTING A LED LINE UNDER LOCATIONLISTENER (LOCATIONLISTENER CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO A TYPE)
PLEASE HAVE A LOOK. I FOLLOWED THE METHOD FROM GOOGLE DEVELOPERS SITE. THANKS

"package com.xxxxxxx;

```
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity<MapController> extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService 
   (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
          makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
         };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  
         locationListener);
           }

protected void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
       }"
```

GETTING A LED LINE UNDER LOCATIONLISTENER (LOCATIONLISTENER CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO A TYPE)
PLEASE HAVE A LOOK. I FOLLOWED THE METHOD FROM GOOGLE DEVELOPERS SITE. THANKS

Comment: Why are you YELLING at us?

Answer (score 4):

Add `import android.location.LocationListener;` to your list of imports.

Also, your CAPS LOCK key seems to be broken. You might want a new keyboard.

Comment: +1: Didn't read your answer, I just saw something about caps lock and immediately kicked the upvote button :P

Comment: ha wanted to make to look stand apart from the code. Sorry to anyone who felt offended!